# Animated GIF shows all layers instead 1 after 1

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, animation, gif

I used an existing GIF and deleted the background on all layers. I saved it again with a transparent background. The image is 150 layers. It a a growing figure (like an opening flower). From layer 78 tot 150 it goes back to where it started (flower closes again in reverse order).

When playing the animation in Photoshop one layer is selected for each frame in the timeline panel, but when I save it as a GIF (dithered 128) and then view it, layer 1–78 go alright one by one, but when it reverse from 78–150 it keeps all the previous layers visible!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you just save it as GIF file via *Save as...*?
If that's what you did, go with *Export > Save For Web* instead.

Comment: What you need to do is *replace* the layer instead of putting it on top of the other. The background used to obscure the previous layer, but with a transparent one you keep seeing them...

Comment: In GIMP the setting is called Frame Disposal (One frame per layer), I don't know what it is in PS.

Comment: @Alex: I saved it as save for web
@ PieBie? How do I replace a layer? as The first 80 layers are working just fine and are the same as layes 80-150.

Answer (score 20):

**Frame Disposal:**

- Select all Frames in Timeline
- Right-Click on one frame
- Select Dispose

  [image]

Comment: perfectly works

Comment: god thank you i don't even know how this got changed but it was making me crazy