# How to transparent gif in Photoshop (version 20)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, gif

I want to transparent the background color of the spider filter (in Snapchat), and I used "Quick Selection Tool" to transparent the background color, in Photoshop everything seemed right, but when I exported it as a GIf the previous one is still there and also about the background color isn't transparent:

[image]

Here is my setting in Save for Web:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animated GIF shows all layers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64065/animated-gif-shows-all-layers-instead-1-after-1)

Comment: Thank you @BillyKerr